Next.js Middleware issue: Not triggering while hiting protected routes
I am using Next.js version 14.1.0, and I have created a file named middleware.js in the src directory. My src folder contains the following subdirectories:

app
common
components

Within the app directory, there is a subdirectory named student among others. I am trying to protect the student route using middleware.
Here is the content of my middleware.js file:

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
 
// This function can be marked `async` if using `await` inside
export function middleware(request) {

    const path = request.nextUrl.pathname

    const isPublicPath = path === '/login' || path === '/signup' 
    const token = request.cookies.get('token')?.value || ''

    if(isPublicPath && token){
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/' , request.nextUrl))
    }

    if(!isPublicPath && !token){
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login' , request.nextUrl))
    }

}
 
export const config = {
  matcher: '/student/:path*',
}

Here is my next.config.mjs file
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
//  skipTrailingSlashRedirect: true,
//  trailingSlash: true,
//  output: 'export',

api: {
  bodyParser: {
    sizeLimit: "20mb",
  },
},

  images: {
    domains: ['20.78.10.88'],
  },

};
  
export default nextConfig;


Here is my jsconfig.json file
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}

I suspect there might be an issue related to some missing configurations in the next.config.mjs file and jsconfig.json file. What could be the possible solution to resolve this issue?

Is the token empty when the function is called?

@Ofirfr i am testing it in the private tab , there is no token present. i also verify by inspecting application tab in the browser

Can you log the values of isPublicPath and token when the page is rendered and paste them here?

@Ofirfr i am unable to see the log values of these variables

Why is that? Maybe the code is not even invoked? Please check both client and server logs

@UmarRaza, could you double-check that the middleware.js is at the same level as the app folder? Also, I would recommend to add return NextResponse.next() in the last line of the middleware

EweTekMin i had tried but this is also not work

@UmarRaza, in that case, you may wanna change the matcher to match all paths because your middleware will only run for the /student/* path. You may wanna make the changes If you want to cover the login and signup paths too

@EweTekMin some how i figure out that the project don't know where is the middleware.js file , i think server is unable to locate the middleware.js file
